# My rails application(in local) suddenly stop responding to requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, puma

I have been working on a rails application for the past four months. Suddenly one-day puma server stops responding to the requests.
Here is what I see in the terminal:

```
$ rails s  
=> Booting Puma  
=> Rails 5.1.7 application starting in development   
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options  
 Puma starting in single mode...  
 Puma version: 5.5.2 (ruby 2.6.3-p62) ("Zawgyi")  
  Min threads: 5  
  Max threads: 5  
  Environment: development  
          PID: 12446  
 Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000  
 Listening on http://[::1]:3000  
Use Ctrl-C to stop   
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2021-11-10 12:28:58 +0530  
Started GET "/recommendations" for ::1 at 2021-11-10 12:29:20 +0530  
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2021-11-10 12:29:39 +0530  
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2021-11-10 12:29:40 +0530
```

I tried many things like changing the port, making sure that the rails version in my local and gemfile are the same, trying with other ruby versions, uninstalling and reinstalling ruby and rails in local.
Tried keeping binding.pry in the application controller's index action but that not getting hit. I am not able to exit from that point, the server gets stuck there. There are no recent changes in my application.

Can anyone suggest to me what might be the problem?

Comment: Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: You have 5 threads working, your server fails on the 5th request... could be related? ... sidetone: nothing obviously changed, computers don't behave differently unless instructed to.

Comment: It's not processing from the first request onwards. I gave 4 requests and posted that code, if we give 5th request it just takes and do nothing.

Comment: Finally, found out the reason behind this, it is because of a change in security in my machine.

Comment: @ManojPogadadanda , what do you mean a change in security? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @JamesHulse, I faced this issue on my organization's laptop where they made changes to security which they will not disclose to me. After this security update, my application is not able to communicate with a database that is on azure. So, I took the database from azure to my local, it started working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ManojPogadadanda. My issue must have been different. I updated the Puma web server from 5.6.0 to 5.6.1, so there must have been an issue in that version.